# How to code a Date Range in SQL QUERY to go back 3 weeks from the current date and and Go forward 1 week from the current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, date-arithmetic

-- This code only pulls due dates within the next 7 days,it's ignoring the last 21 days
--How to code a Date Range in SQL QUERY  to go back 3 weeks  from the current date and and Go forward 1 week from the current date

```
select top 10  D.VendID as Customer , D.DueDate, sum(CuryTranAmt) as Amount, C.CpnyName Company 
  from APTran A
  left join APDoc D
  on A.RefNbr = D.RefNbr
  inner join [SIVSYS].[dbo].[Company] C
  on D.CpnyID = C.CpnyID

  where 
  A.trantype NOT IN ('CK', 'HC')
  and A.DrCr like 'C'
  and (D.DueDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, -21, GETDATE())) OR (D.DueDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, +7, GETDATE()))

  and D.DocBal <> '0'

  group by 
  D.VendID
 ,C.CpnyName
 ,D.DueDate
 ,A.CuryTranAmt
 ,D.RefNbr
 ,D.BatNbr
 order by (A.CuryTranAmt) desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You first condition has bounds of `between` inverted: the lowest bound is greater than the upper bound, so no date can match on that.

I think that you just want:

```
where d.dueDate 
    between dateadd(day, -21, getdate())
    and dateadd(day, 7, getdate())
```

Possibly, you want the entire days, so:

```
where 
    d.dueDate >= dateadd(day, -21, cast(getdate() as date))
    and d.dueDate < dateadd(day, 6, cast(getdate() as date))
```